# Increment action bar View Badger on button click by using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, cart

I am working on an e-commerce assignment and I want to add item into the cart on button click `Add To Cart` when I click on the button item need to added in the cart and view badger needs to increment.

So this operation I want to perform with in the `Fragment`, if you don't understand my question then take a look to snapshots you will understand what I want to ask?

when there is no items in the cart-
[image]

when I click on button cart item added into the cart and it shows like this..
[image]

so how can I perform this action using `Fragments` and increment the view badger.Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try with below solution, if you still have problem, please let me know I will send you the example.

```
private int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button increaseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.increaseButton);
    increaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doIncrease();
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.testAction);
    menuItem.setIcon(buildCounterDrawable(count, R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery));

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private Drawable buildCounterDrawable(int count, int backgroundImageId) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.counter_menuitem_layout, null);
    view.setBackgroundResource(backgroundImageId);

    if (count == 0) {
        View counterTextPanel = view.findViewById(R.id.counterValuePanel);
        counterTextPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
        textView.setText("" + count);
    }

    view.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
}

private void doIncrease() {
    count++;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: sorry to ask you but can you give an example.

Comment: yes, that's fine. Please download [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4E1qxhiuLQ6Smw2a00xSHdmRUE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you give me one more solution I want to add item in cart and display them on other activity on click on the cart icon

Comment: I think it would be better if you can create new question, give me link. In case of I am busy then other guys can help you. Best Regards,

Comment: @MinhBui I am not using default menu and I have a custom toolbar. How can I implement badges their? Please suggest

Comment: @MinhBui I have created a new question with code. 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547837/android-create-badge-on-custom-toolbar-without-menu-items)