# android create badge on custom toolbar without menu items

Tags: android, android-toolbar

In my app we have to use custom app-bar/ToolBar.
With that now we have to implement badge (add cart with counting).

**below is my tool-bar xml (toolbar.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue_074A92"
    android:elevation="@dimen/appbar_elevation"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/default_action_bar"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="left">            

            <ImageView
                style="@style/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_language"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/app_bar_ln_text_size"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/worlwide"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_bar_tbv_margin_left_right"/>
            <TextView
                style="@style/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_language_txt"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/app_bar_ln_txt_text_size"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="@string/ln_english_txt"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_ot"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                style="@style/appbar_iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_title"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/app_bar_text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="right">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tv_search"
                style="@style/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_bar_tbv_margin_left_right"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:text="@string/icon_search"
                android:src="@drawable/shopping_cart"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tv_logout"
                style="@style/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_bar_tbv_margin_left_right"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:text="@string/icon_logout"
                android:src="@drawable/magnifying_glass"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/search_action_bar"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="85"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/search_bottom_border"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                style="@style/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="90"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/et_search"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:hint="@string/search_txt"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey_ecebf1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="@drawable/empty_bottom_border"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/icon_cancel"
                android:id="@+id/cancel_search_bar"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:clickable="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="right">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_logout_1"
                style="@style/app_bar"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_bar_tbv_margin_left_right"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:text="@string/icon_logout"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

My current fragment code to access the app-bar in firstfragment.java file

```
private void setUpTopBar(){
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            LinearLayout default_action_bar = (LinearLayout)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.default_action_bar);
            default_action_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            TextView tv_activity_title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tv_toolbar_title);
            tv_activity_title.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.title_activity_home));

            ImageView tv_language = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tv_language);
            tv_language.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_language.setOnClickListener(this);

            tv_language_txt = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tv_language_txt);
            tv_language_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_language_txt.setOnClickListener(this);

            ImageView tv_search = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tv_search);
            tv_search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }
```

**My current view is looking like :**

[image]

And Actually I want the counter on cart image which looks like

[image]

Please suggest

Comment: where is the counter code in the xml?

Comment: I tried to add that but failed to add it so removed that code

Comment: @Pallavi, have you still needed to have solution with this question? Sorry, I was too busy long time..

Comment: @MinhBui Thanks, I have implemented it by icon-moon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add item number on the cart icon at top toolbar? Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39496301/how-to-add-item-number-on-the-cart-icon-at-top-toolbar-android)